# Pattern matching maps as function arguments

Tags: elixir

I'm having trouble writing function clauses where I need to pattern-match against the map and also retain it for use in the function. I'm not able to understand what the syntax will be. Basically I want something like this:

```
def check_data (arg1, %{"action" => "action1", ...}, arg2) do
  # access other keys of the structure
end
```

I'm sure this is very basic, but it's something that seems to be eluding me. I've gone through many tutorials but can't seem to find one that handles this use case.

Comment: You mean like `def check_data(%{"action" => "action1"} = arg1, arg2)` or `def check_data(arg1, %{"action" => "action1"} = arg2)`?

Comment: @Dogbert No, no. What I meant to show was that there are other arguments besides the map. Can we do `arg1 =  %{}` inside function parameters? :O

Comment: So `def check_data(arg1, %{"action" => "action1"} = map, arg2)`? Yes, you can use `=` in function parameters.

Comment: @Dogbert Another revelation! Thanks so much. Mind adding this as an answer? :-)

Comment: @Dogbert And I guess we can match maps partially? I mean, it doesn't matter that other fields there are, as long as `"action"` matches in our case, right?

Comment: Yes, maps are always matched partially. The map must contain everything specified in the pattern and anything else in the map is ignored.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To match some keys of a map and also store the whole map in a variable, you can use `= variable` with the pattern:

```
def check_data(arg1, %{"action" => "action1"} = map, arg2) do
end
```

This function will match any map containing the `"action1"` in the key `"action"` (and any other key/value pairs) as the 2nd argument, and store the whole map in `map`:

```
iex(1)> defmodule Main do
...(1)>   def check_data(_arg1, %{"action" => "action1"} = map, _arg2), do: map
...(1)> end
iex(2)> Main.check_data :foo, %{}, :bar
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Main.check_data/3
    iex:2: Main.check_data(:foo, %{}, :bar)
iex(2)> Main.check_data :foo, %{"action" => "action1"}, :bar
%{"action" => "action1"}
iex(3)> Main.check_data :foo, %{"action" => "action1", :foo => :bar}, :bar
%{:foo => :bar, "action" => "action1"}
```